# What does "troubled the counsels of the Wise and the Great" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> But in the days of Bilbo, and of Frodo his heir, they suddenly became, by no wish of their own, both important and renowned, and ***troubled the counsels of the Wise and the Great***.

I usually see 'trouble', as a verb, is often followed by a person, e.g. *trouble you*.  But I don't understand "troubled the counsels" in the quote.

What does the phrase mean here?

Comment: Is it so hard to get the terms right in a cut and paste? http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/The_Council_of_Elrond

Comment: He troubles you. = You were troubled **by him**.

Comment: *The **counsels** of the Wise and the Great* is an obsolete / archaic usage (OED II.7 *A body or group of advisers; an adviser, consultant).* And *the Wise and the Great,* which [was never very common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+Wise+and+the+Great%2Cthe+Great+and+the+Good&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) compared to *the Great and the Good*, is virtually unknown today outside of Tolkein's use.

Comment: @Lambie this is from the Prologue, and doesn't refer to the Council of Elrond.  There was a spelling error but that's been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They suddenly **became** [by no wish of their own] both important and renowned (1),
>
> and [they] **troubled** the counsels of the Wise and the Great (2).

As you correctly pointed out, *trouble* can be a verb and it's the role it plays in this passage. It's presented in the past simple form. It's a regular verb, thus *trouble - troubled - troubled*.

When you **trouble** (verb) someone, you **cause** them **trouble** (noun).

In our sentence, they troubled **the counsels**. Counsels are basically people you go to in order to receive some piece of advice (or, to put it old-fashionedly or formally, [counsel](https://www.etymonline.com/word/counsel#etymonline_v_19152)). Nowadays, *counsel* is usually used to refer to **a layer** who gives legal advice or/and takes part in legal cases.

Moreover, they troubled the counsels **of the Wise and the Great**. Counsels tend to be highly intelligent and competent because they are expected to provide their "clients" with sound and valuable advice on complicated matters. And *of the Wise and the Great* is just a nice old-fashioned way to emphasise that, to stress that even exceptionally wise and highly regarded members of society were troubled by them.

Comment: As a side question, " in the days of Bilbo, and of Frodo his heir", is "his" referring to Bilbo's?

Comment: @dan yes.  Bilbo and Frodo are (both first and second) cousins, but [Bilbo adopts Frodo](https://www.looper.com/368232/lord-of-the-rings-how-bilbo-and-frodo-are-actually-related/) as his heir when he (Bilbo) turned 99

Answer (score 7):

Tolkien tends to use words in an old fashioned style. He is trying to write with majesty and poise, and frequently uses words that had already become rare in English at the time he was writing.

In this case "counsel" means the consultation that kings hold with their advisors and ministers. And "trouble" means "disturb, or make turbulent".

So, the actions of Bilbo and Frodo had a great effect on the politics of the world, even though this was unintentional.

Comment: I think that what was unintentional was Bilbo and Frodo;s  importance and renown, not the troubling they contributed to the Council of Elrond.

Comment: This question/answer doesn't directly relate to the Council of Elrond.  It is the "counsels of the Wise and Great" referred to in the Prologue to LotR

Comment: I stand corrected thanks as to the source of the quote. I still think the fame was the unintentional part. Not relevant for the question, of course.